# Seg fault on exit() call

Tags: c, server, client, one-time-password

I'm writing a program that simulates a server and a client for one time passwords. The client sends a plaintext OR ciphertext file and a key file. The server listens for a client process, which sends a buffer containing a method (either encryption (otp_enc) or decryption (otp_dec) and two file names (input_file_name, and key_file_name). The program opens the files and writes either plaintext or ciphertext to a buffer and sends back to client which prints the output.

The user calls on the command line:

```
otp_dec_d [port_number] & (server runs in background) 
otp_dec plaintext_file_name key_file_name [port_number]
```

The program works perfect, except I am trying to set the exit status to 2 if the methods do not match w/ the port number, like so...

```
otp_dec_d 56780 &
otp_enc_d 56781 &
otp_enc plaintext_file_name key_file_name 56780
```

And I am getting a segfault. Any idea why? I point out below the line thats doing it. The rest of the program works perfectly, blank output is sent back to the client just as it should be if this error prints. (if(strcmp(argv[0], method) != 0) is the if statement)

```
//header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include "otp.h" 

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(1); } // Error function used for reporting issues
/*
    Name: server
    -----------------
    Description:
        This function simulates a server
        Reads buffer input from the client 
        Tokenizes string
        Opens files for writing specified in arguments list
        Calls appropriate function for encrypt/decrypt 
        Sends back an output file

    Parameters: 
        argv[] list from stdin (ex: otp_dec_d or otp_enc_d [port_number])
*/
int server(char* argv[])
{ 
    //printf("%s %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);    //for testing purposes

    int listenSocketFD, establishedConnectionFD, portNumber, charsRead;
    socklen_t sizeOfClientInfo;
    char buffer[300];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;

    pid_t spawnPid = -5;                            //garbage value

    char method[100];                               //array to hold method name (otp_enc,or otp_dec)
    char input_file_name[100];                      //array to hold input file name
    char key_file_name[100];                        //array to hold key file name

    char output_file_name[300] = "output_file";     //array to hold output file name (output_file)   

    char input[70000];                              //array to hold recv file contents
    char output[70000];                             //array to hold send file contents
    char key[70000];                                //array to hold key file contents

    int port;                                       //int value to hold argv[1]

    // Set up the address struct for this process (the server)
    memset((char *)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress)); // Clear out the address struct
    portNumber = atoi(argv[1]); // Get the port number, convert to an integer from a string
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; // Create a network-capable socket
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNumber); // Store the port number
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Any address is allowed for connection to this process

    // Set up the socket
    listenSocketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create the socket
    if (listenSocketFD < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    // Enable the socket to begin listening
    if (bind(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) // Connect socket to port
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(listenSocketFD, 5); // Flip the socket on - it can now receive up to 5 connections

    while(1) {

        // Accept a connection, blocking if one is not available until one connects
        sizeOfClientInfo = sizeof(clientAddress); // Get the size of the address for the client that will connect
        establishedConnectionFD = accept(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sizeOfClientInfo); // Accept
        if (establishedConnectionFD < 0) error("ERROR on accept");

        spawnPid = fork(); 

        switch(spawnPid) {
            case -1:   
                perror("Hull Breach!\n");
                exit(1);
                break;
            case 0:
                // Get the message from the client and display it
                memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));
                charsRead = recv(establishedConnectionFD, buffer, strlen(buffer)-1, 0); // Read the client's message from the socket
                if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
                //printf("SERVER: I received this from the client: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

                //tokenize input from client 
                char* token = strtok(buffer, "\n"); 
                strcpy(method, token);              //transfer current value to method array  
                token = strtok(NULL, "\n");         //reset token
                strcpy(input_file_name, token);     //transfer current value to input_file_name array
                token = strtok(NULL, "\n");         //reset token
                strcpy(key_file_name, token);       //transfer current value to key_file_name array

                //printf("%s %s %s %s\n", method, input_file_name, key_file_name); //for testing purposes

                //printf("%d\n", port);    //for testing purposes 
                strcat(method, "_d");      //add _d to end of method 

                if(strcmp(argv[0], method) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not contact %s on %s", argv[0], argv[1]); 
                    exit(2);  //SEG_FAULT HERE!!!!!  
                }

                else { 
                    //open input and key files for reading
                    FILE* input_file = fopen(input_file_name, "r"); 
                    FILE* key_file = fopen(key_file_name, "r"); 

                    //transfer file contents to arrays
                    fgets(input, 70000, input_file); 
                    fgets(key, 70000, key_file); 

                    //close files
                    fclose(input_file); 
                    fclose(key_file);

                    //remove trailing newlines from arrays
                    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0'; 
                    key[strcspn(key, "\n")] = '\0';

                    //printf("%s\n%s\n", input, key);     //for testing purposes
                    //printf("%s\n", argv[0]); 

                    //printf("%s\n", method);            //for testing purposes 

                    /* --------------------- Handle encrypt v. decrypt --------------------- */ 
                    //if argument 1 in argv array is encrypt 
                    if(strcmp("otp_enc_d", method) == 0)
                        encrypt(input, output, key); 

                    //else if argument 1 in argv array is decrypt 
                    else if(strcmp("otp_dec_d", method) == 0)
                        decrypt(input, output, key);   

                    /* ------------------- End handle encrypt v. decrypt ------------------- */ 
                }

                //printf("%s\n", output);             //for testing purposes

                //Open output file and write contents to it 
                FILE* output_file = fopen(output_file_name, "w+");
                fprintf(output_file, "%s", output); 

                // Send a Success message back to the client
                charsRead = send(establishedConnectionFD, output_file_name, strlen(output_file_name), 0); // Send success back
                //printf("%d\n", charsRead); 
                if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

                // Close the existing socket which is connected to the client
                close(establishedConnectionFD); 
                establishedConnectionFD = -1; 
                exit(0); 
                break; 

            default: ;
        }
                close(establishedConnectionFD); 
                establishedConnectionFD = -1;
                wait(NULL); 
    }

    close(listenSocketFD); // Close the listening socket

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: First figure out if the crash happens in the parent or the child process. Use a debugger to try and catch the crash in the parent process. If it doesn't do that then the crash happens in the child process, and you need to attach the debugger to the child process. Also use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help catch memory errors (like buffer overruns), which could be a likely cause of your crash.

Comment: You *do* use uninitialized data in your program though, in ways which leads to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes. See `memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));`. Remember what `strlen` uses to find the end of the *null-terminated* string? Perhaps you meant to use `sizeof` instead of `strlen`?